# BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object'

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm new to wpf and I'm trying use a DataTemplate to create menu, to learn how to use DataTemplates.

I get the following binding error and no text appears in the control and I can't see why.

Binding Error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object' ''StartOptionsViewModel' (HashCode=7730701)'. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayName; DataItem='StartOptionsViewModel' (HashCode=7730701); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

MainWindow.XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Colin's Test Application" Width="600" Height="400">
    <Window.Resources>

    <!-- WIZARD STEP TEMPLATE -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OptionsTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="bdOuter" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" CornerRadius="12" Margin="1,1,1,12" Opacity="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                <Border x:Name="bdInner" Background="#FFFEFEFE" BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="2,2,1,1" CornerRadius="12" Padding="2" >
                  <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Margin="4,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StartOptions}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionsTemplate}" 
        />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My MainWindoViewModel.cs

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private List<StartOptionsViewModel> _listStartOptionsVM = new List<StartOptionsViewModel>();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _listStartOptionsVM.AddRange(new StartOptionsViewModel[] 
        { 
            new StartOptionsViewModel(new StartOption("New Application", StartOption.StartOptionTypes.Button)),
            new StartOptionsViewModel(new StartOption("Exit Application", StartOption.StartOptionTypes.Button))
        });
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<StartOptionsViewModel> StartOptions 
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<StartOptionsViewModel>(_listStartOptionsVM);
        }
    }
}
```

`
StartOptionsViewModel.cs:

```
public class StartOptionsViewModel
{
    private StartOption m_startOption = null;
    public StartOptionsViewModel(StartOption p_startOption)
    {
        m_startOption = p_startOption;
    }

    #region Properties

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return m_startOption.DisplayName; }
        set
        {
            //...
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `OneWayToSource` binds from `Xaml` to the `object`, `OneWay` is from the `object` to the `Xaml`, in your case you want to use `OneWay` because you have no setter on the object and `TextBlock` can't be edited.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are binding your textblock mode in wrong way because textbox text never be set from ui means on runtime by user son it' smode can't be onewaytosource it should be one way so first you should have correct that like this..

```
 <TextBlock
    x:Name="txt"
    Margin="4,0,0,0"
    Foreground="Black"
    Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"
    />
```

first make it correct and run your code and comment if your problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've made the change you suggest but I still get the same problem.

Comment: I don't understand this because from the error it is pointing at the correct class and looking at the correct property and I know the property exists on the class and the return type is correct.